# Animate SVG javascript object

Tags: javascript, animation, google-maps-api-3, svg

Is it possible to create an SVG object and add animation to it? The end goal is that I can use it as a google map marker. I can create an SVG an use it as a marker like below, but I have not found any resources which would tell me what options, if any, are available for defining animation

```
var icon = {
         path: 'M0,-1 V1 M-1,0 H1',
         scale: 2,
         strokeColor: 'red',
         strokeWeight: 2
     }

     var labelMarker = new MarkerWithLabel({
         name: "a name",
         position: homeLatLng,
         map: map,
         icon: icon,
         draggable: true,
         raiseOnDrag: true,
         labelContent: html,
         labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(19, 44),
         labelInBackground: false
     });
```

*note this code uses an extension of Markers class but functions the same

Comment: There are various options, SMIL animations, CSS animations or javascript manipulation of the DOM with setTimeout

Comment: sorry I don't quite follow. how might I apply these to my svg object?

Comment: There are plenty of examples out there if you search for them. If you show what you're trying to do we can comment.

Comment: Worth noting some animation can be done via the marker settings as opposed to direct svg markup. Like here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations If you want something beyond that type of thing, maybe put a jsfiddle up with an example and describe what you are after.